# Radius of convergence problem.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the power series $\sum a_nx^n$ with radius of convergence R .

a) Prove that if all the coefficients $a_n$ are integers and infinitely many of them are non zero then , R is less then equal to 1 .

What i did : Since $a_n$'s are integral values , thus there must exist an integer "b" such that $|a_n|$ >=b ;
so , $|a_n|^{1/n}$ >=  $|b|^{1/n}$ , implies Sup$|a_n|^{1/n}$ >= $|b|^{1/n}$ ;
Applying limit on both sides , we get Lt Sup$|a_n|^{1/n}$ >= Lt $|b|^{1/n}$ ,
Thus Lt Sup$|a_n|^{1/n}$ >= 1 ; 
Taking the reciprocal and we get R <= 1;

b) Prove that if limsup$|a_n|$ > 0 , then R <= 1 .

What i did : 
Since limsup$|a_n|$ > 0 thus  limsup$|a_n|^{1/n}$ > 0 ;
let  limsup$|a_n|^{1/n}$ = A which is > 0 ,
so , (1/ limsup$|a_n|^{1/n}$) = (1/A) or R = 1/A ;
now A is a positive non-zero integer , so 1/A <= 1 , or R <= 1 ;

Is the above proof correct ?

Comment: You can use \geq or \leq command for $\geq$ and $\leq$.

Comment: Use `\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}` to get $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) If $R>1,$ you would have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|x^n < \infty$ for some $x>1.$ But infinitely many $|a_n| \ge 1,$ so $|a_n|x^n$ can't even $\to 0,$ contradiction.

(b) If $\limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n| > 0,$ then there exists $c>0$ such that $|a_{n_k}| > c$ for some subsequence $n_k.$ Thus $\limsup_{k\to \infty}|a_{n_k}|^{1/n_k} \ge \limsup_{k\to \infty}m^{1/n_k} =1.$ Because

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} \ge \limsup_{k\to \infty} a_{n_k}^{n_k} \ge 1,$$

we obtain $R\le 1.$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is lacking.

You say:

> There exists an integer $b$ such that $|a_n|\geq b$

This statement is not a correct mathematical statement, because $n$ here is not known.

I presume you want to say that $|a_n|\geq b$ *for all values $n$*, but in that case, that is simply not true, since you can have $a_1=1,a_2=0,a_3=1,a_4=0\dots$

Comment: So how do we proceed ? We have to consider such an inequality somehow .. Right ?

Comment: @RohitDuggal Well, you need a similar inequality. Try to remember what $\limsup$ is.

Comment: can we consider limsup[a(n)] >= Lim a(n) ; and then let Lim a(n) = a and the rest as above ?

Comment: @RohitDuggal No, because $a_n$ may not have a limit.

Comment: so can u suggest something please ?

Comment: @RohitDuggal I did, 11 minutes ago. $11$ minutes is not enough time for you to properly think about things, so I will not provide further hints. You got the problem in order to learn. If I tell you the result, you learn nothing. Take a look at the problem, take a look at the textbook you have, see how similar problems were solved in the textbook, and try several things. Most will fail. That is how you learn.